# Why do nouns sometimes take an article and sometimes not?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, articles, groupe-nominal

I don't understand why in some cases, nouns have to add the word “le/la/l'” in front of them (e.g: in the structure “avoir l'intention de...” or “avoir l'air de”). However in some other cases, there is no “le/la/l'” going with nouns (e.g.: in the structure “avoir besoin de” or “avoir envie de”). Why?

Comment: What examples do you have in mind with NPs following *avoir l'intention de* or *avoir l'air de*? It would help describing the contrast with *avoir besoin de la clé* or *avoir envie de la bonne tarte de maman*.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you'll be able to find a satisfactory answer to this, because when it comes down to it, language isn't always logical. In fact, these expressions have English equivalents with the same article or lack thereof.

1. *avoir besoin de* = to have need of
2. *avoir l'intention de* = to have the intention to
3. *avoir l'air de* = to have the look of

Why do 2 and 3 have "the" but 1 doesn't? If you can find the answer to that, it's exactly the same for French.

Answer (score 2):

The examples you give where there is no article are "[Locutions verbales](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Locutions_verbales_en_fran%C3%A7ais)", i.e. frozen expressions that have the same value as a simple verb.

There are no rules to sort out *locutions verbales*. Some of them include an article, some don't, that's the way they are.

You simply have to know them, just like there is no logical way for a non English speaker to guess "to give up" even if he already knows both "to give" and "up".

Comment: Thank you, Jilliagre :) but the ones having article also indicate the same meaning as its simple verb. I still dont get the difference :(